# How to change Tor exit node when using multiple SocksPort

Tags: tor

I'm using Tor with multiple SocksPort. Does anyone know how I can programmatically change the exit for each SockPort separately? The code below changes the exit nodes for all the SocksPort -- I want to be able to do it individually. Is there a way to assign a separate control port to each SocksPort or tell the control port to change the exit node for a specific SocksPort?

```
echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE "password"\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```

I'm on Linux. Thanks.